# Showing different content in Facebook iframe WITHOUT using "Like"

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

OK, this is not the question you might think. We need to set up a tab on a Facebook page & of course that now means iframes, not FBML.

The initial content displayed will be a graphic containing a question. The answer, in the shape of another graphic, is to be revealed by clicking on the first image. The initial image must be replaced by the second (which shows the answer).

"Like" does not enter in to this: the function is the same whether the user "likes" the page or not. It's just "click this image to display the answer".

As iframe newbs, this is causing us a bit of a headache - so can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: I really can't understand a bit of what you are saying!

Answer (score 0):

The iframes in Facebook now function just like a normal web page. Just capture the click event on the initial image using javascript (and/or jQuery) and display replace it with the new imagery.